# Javascript subtraction returns NaN

Tags: javascript, nan, subtraction

What is wrong with my code?? Everything except the subtraction works. It just returns NaN. I am new to javascript so i might have written my code poorly.

```
// Variables
var count = prompt("Choose an arithmetic method: \n1. Addition \n2.     Subtraktion\n3. Multiplikation\n4. Division");
var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter your first number", "0"));
var y = parseInt(prompt("Enter your second number", "0"));
var z = +x + +y;


// Switch function with 4 cases
switch(count) {
case '1':
alert("Answer: " + z);
break;

case '2':
alert("Answer: " + x - y);
break;

case '3':
alert("Answer: " + x * y);
break;

case '4':
alert("Answer: " + x / y);
break;
```

}

Comment: whats this: `var z = +x + +y;` ?

Comment: @JordanHendrix It's the unary plus. It converts Strings to Numbers. `+"10" === 10` (even though it's not needed here because of the `parseInt`s)

Comment: @blex for some reason the parseInts didn't work so i had to add the var z = +x + +y;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to group the operations in parentheses, for instance `alert("Answer: " + (x - y));` (and the same for the others). Otherwise JavaScript runs `"Answer: " + x` first, resulting in a string.

Also, always specify the radix (you want 10) for parseInt: `parseInt(input, 10)`, otherwise some engines get confused with octal numbers.

Comment: Tank you so much everyone!

Answer (score 4):

Your trouble is here:

```
alert("Answer: " + x - y);
```

Due to how the association of operators work, it works as if you had written this:

```
alert(("Answer: " + x) - y);
```

You need to write it like this:

```
alert("Answer: " + (x - y));
```

Snippet here:

```js
// Variables
var count = prompt("Choose an arithmetic method: \n1. Addition \n2.     Subtraktion\n3. Multiplikation\n4. Division");
var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter your first number", "0"));
var y = parseInt(prompt("Enter your second number", "0"));
var z = +x + +y;


// Switch function with 4 cases
switch (count) {
  case '1':
    alert("Answer: " + z);
    break;

  case '2':
    alert("Answer: " + (x - y));
    break;

  case '3':
    alert("Answer: " + x * y);
    break;

  case '4':
    alert("Answer: " + x / y);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your subtraction in parentheses: (x - y). You would get an unexpected result from the addition, too, if you put x + y there instead of z.

What's happening is operator precedence. Multiplication and division are higher precedence than addition, so they get done first - before the implicit conversion to string for concatenation.

With subtraction, '+' and '-' are equal in precedence and so get done in order from left to right. So the concat takes place before the math, which leaves you attempting to subtract y from a string (which doesn't work, and so...NaN).

With addition, it would simply concatenate the two numbers onto the string.